# How to capture a screenshot of ios simulator using code, and get the captured screenshot as a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

The requirement is capture the on-screen content displayed as a UIImage, and then perform a custom dismiss animation on that image.

Comment: Press Command + S button when your simulator is running. :) It will save the complete simulator shot on desktop.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code will get you a UIImage of the passed view. To get a image of the whole screen, pass `self.view` inside some UIViewController of yours

```
- (UIImage*)screenShotOfView:(UIView *)view
{
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
     [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     return image;
}
```

Comment: i got it working using UIgetScreenImage and later using UIView Animation blocks :)
thanks anyway !!

Answer (score 0):

The first one, captureView, returns a UIImage that contains a render of any UIView (except EAGLView, see below). If you pass your app’s UIWindow into this method, it will return you a screenshot of the app.

The second method, saveScreenshotToPhotosAlbum, takes it a step further and saves an image that contains a render of any UIView to your iPhone’s photo album.

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView *)view 

{

        CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [view.layer renderInContext:context];
        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return img;

}



(void)saveScreenshotToPhotosAlbum:(UIView *)view 
{

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self captureView:view], nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: @Vamit : i got it working using UIgetScreenImage and later using UIView Animation blocks :)
thanks anyway !!

Answer (score -1):

Press Command + Shift + 4 then select the simulator and snapshot will be saved at your desktop, then drag the saved image to the simulator and will open on safari ... long tab to save image ... and now u can get the image from photos library on simulator.

Comment: actually i need to take screen image using coding and use that image to perform a custom animation....plz suggest some  api or lines of code @IslamAhmed

Comment: u have to image context and start drawing layers on it ... then save it as image ... `- (UIImage*)screenShotOfView:(UIView *)view
{
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
     [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     return image;
}`   to save use this `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self captureView:view], nil, nil, nil);` as @lucas-eduardo said ... I think it's the only way